# Cuda Pytorch Error: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to train a deep neural network on cuda. I found some code and I am trying to make it compatible to cuda. My code is as below:

```py
class UnsupervisedModel(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(UnsupervisedModel, self).__init__()

        # Encoder
        encoder_net = get_learning_net("cnn1d_fe",
                                     {"input_channels": 1,
                                      "dropout": 0,
                                      "kernel_size": 3,
                                      "stride": 1,
                                      "mid_channels": 32,
                                      "final_out_channels": 64},
                                     state_dict=None,
                                     freeze=False)
        # Linear Classifier (single layer)
        #classifier_net = get_neural_net(name='LinearNN',
                                        #args={"input_dim": 64,
                                              #"output_dim": 2},
                                        #state_dict=None)

        self.encoder_net = encoder_net
        #self.classifier_net = classifier_net

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder_net(x)
        #x = self.classifier_net(x)
        return x
```

```py
def main(args):

    # reproducibility
    random.seed(args.seed)
    np.random.seed(args.seed)
    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(args.seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = False
    torch.use_deterministic_algorithms = True

    # set GPU device ID
    device = "cuda:0"
    args.device = device
    logging.info('Torch, using device: %s' % device)
    criter_cl=NTXentLoss(device, args.batch_size, 0.5, True)

    # Data loaders
    #train_loader_1, validation_loader_1, test_loader_1 = prepare_data_loaders(args)
    train_loader, validation_loader, test_loader = prepare_unseen_data_loaders(args)
    from models.helpers import proj_head
    proj_head = proj_head(args.input_length)
    #print(proj_head)
    feature_extractor=UnsupervisedModel()
    temporal_encoder=cnn1d_temporal()
    #projet(feature_extractor)
    from torch import nn
    network = nn.Sequential(feature_extractor, proj_head)
    network.to(device)

    # Model definition
    
    #model = SupervisedModel()
    #model.to(device)
    logging.info(
        'Model initialization, the number of trainable parameters: %d' %
        count_parameters(network))

    # Optimizer and criterion
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([
        {"params": network.parameters()}],lr=args.learning_rate, weight_decay=args.weight_decay, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08)
    #optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([
        #{"params": model.encoder_net.parameters()},
        #{"params": model.classifier_net.parameters()}],
        #lr=args.learning_rate, weight_decay=args.weight_decay, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08)
    loss_func_cl=criter_cl
    #loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    #loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    #metrics = {"loss": Loss(loss_func_cl)}
    metrics = {"loss": Average(output_transform=lambda x: x['loss'])}
    #metrics = {"accuracy": Accuracy(), "loss": Loss(criter_cl)}

    # Features
    # 0: ACC_x
    # 1: ACC_y
    # 2: ACC_z
    # 3: ACC_abs
    # 4: BVP
    # 5: EDA
    # 6: TEMP
    #features = {'EDA':5, 'BVP':4, 'All':[4,5,6]}
    features={'EDA':2, 'BVP':1}
    #[3,4,5,6]
    feature_idx = features[args.feature_type]
    # TODO: Later, adapt network input size/archtitecture to use all features.

    def train_step(engine, train_batch):
        loss = 0
        output_dic = {}

        data,data1, data2,_,_ = train_batch
        #print(data1.shape)
        aug1 = data1[:, feature_idx, :].type(torch.float)
        #print(aug1.shape)
        aug1 = torch.unsqueeze(aug1, dim=1)
        #print(aug1.shape)
        aug2 = data2[:, feature_idx, :].type(torch.float)
        aug2 = torch.unsqueeze(aug2, dim=1)
        
        aug1, aug2 = aug1.to(device), aug2.to(device)

        network.train()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        features1 = feature_extractor(aug1)
        #print(features1.shape)
        z1 = proj_head(features1)
        #print(z1.shape)
        features2 = feature_extractor(aug2)
        z2 = proj_head(features2)
        # normalize projection feature vectors
        z1 = F.normalize(z1, dim=1)
        z2 = F.normalize(z2, dim=1)
        loss = criter_cl(z1, z2)
        #print(loss)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        #print(loss.item())
        #loss += los.detach().item()
        output_dic['loss'] = loss.item()
        #print(total_loss)
        #net=[feature_extractor, temporal_encoder, proj_head]

        return output_dic

    def validation_step(engine, val_batch):
        output_val={}

       
        data,data1, data2,_,_ = val_batch
        #print(data1.shape)
        aug1 = data1[:, feature_idx, :].type(torch.float)
        aug1 = torch.unsqueeze(aug1, dim=1)
        #print(aug1.shape)
        aug2 = data2[:, feature_idx, :].type(torch.float)
        aug2 = torch.unsqueeze(aug2, dim=1)
        
        aug1, aug2 = aug1.to(device), aug2.to(device)

        network.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
             features1 = feature_extractor(aug1)
             z1 = proj_head(features1)
             features2 = feature_extractor(aug2)
             z2 = proj_head(features2)
             z1 = F.normalize(z1, dim=1)
             z2 = F.normalize(z2, dim=1)
             loss = criter_cl(z1, z2)
             output_val['loss'] = loss
            
        return output_val

    # Initialize trainer and evaluators
    trainer = Engine(train_step)
    lr_scheduler = LRScheduler(
        torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(
            optimizer, milestones=[
                2, 10], gamma=0.1))
    trainer.add_event_handler(Events.EPOCH_STARTED, lr_scheduler)
    trainer.logger = setup_logger("Trainer")

    train_evaluator = Engine(validation_step)
    validation_evaluator = Engine(validation_step)
    
 

   
   
    
    trainer.run(train_loader, max_epochs=args.max_epoch)

    # Evaluate the latest snapshot on the entire WESAD dataset
    # Load trained weights
    weight_files = [p for p in list(pathlib.Path(args.log_dir).rglob('*.pt'))]
    print('Loading trained weights: %s' % weight_files[-1].as_posix())
    network.load_state_dict(torch.load(weight_files[-1].as_posix()))
   
    
    network.to(device)
    logging.info(
        'Model initialization, the number of trainable parameters: %d' %
        count_parameters(network))

    for param in network.parameters():  # freeze baseline
            param.requires_grad = False


    train_loader_1, validation_loader_1, test_loader = verbio_data_loaders(args)
    model = SupervisedModel()

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.learning_rate, weight_decay=args.weight_decay, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08)
    loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    print('loss')
    print(Loss(loss_function))
    metrics = {"accuracy": Accuracy(), "loss": Loss(loss_function)}
    
    def train_step_1(engine, train_batch):

        data, labels, metadata = train_batch
        data, labels = data[:, feature_idx, :], labels.squeeze().long()
        data, labels = data.to(device), labels.to(device)
        
        #print(data.shape)
        data=torch.unsqueeze(data, dim=1)

        network.train()

        # forward pass
        emb = network(data)
        output = model(emb)

        # calculate loss
        loss = loss_function(output, labels)
        

        # compute gradient and do SGD step
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        #print(loss.item())

        return loss.item()

    def validation_step_1(engine, val_batch):

        data, labels, metadata = val_batch
        data, labels = data[:, feature_idx, :], labels.squeeze().long()
        data, labels = data.to(device), labels.to(device)
        data=torch.unsqueeze(data, dim=1)

        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            # forward pass
            
            **emb = network(data)**
            **predicted = model(emb)**

        return predicted, labels
    
    
        # Initialize trainer and evaluators
    loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    metrics = {"accuracy": Accuracy(), "loss": Loss(loss_function)}
    trainer = Engine(train_step_1)
    lr_scheduler = LRScheduler(
        torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(
            optimizer, milestones=[
                2, 10], gamma=0.1))
    trainer.add_event_handler(Events.EPOCH_STARTED, lr_scheduler)
    trainer.logger = setup_logger("Trainer")

    train_evaluator = Engine(validation_step_1)
    validation_evaluator = Engine(validation_step_1)




   
    # Kick everything off
    trainer.run(train_loader_1, max_epochs=args.max_epoch)
    # Evaluate the latest snapshot on the entire WESAD dataset
    # Load trained weights for supstream task (freezing)
    ###
    weight_files_1 = [p for p in list(pathlib.Path(args.log_dir_1).rglob('*.pt'))]
    #print('Loading trained weights: %s' % weight_files_1[-1].as_posix())
    
    
    network.load_state_dict(torch.load(weight_files[-1].as_posix()))
    network.to(device)
        
    for param in network.parameters():  # freeze baseline
            param.requires_grad = False
 
    
    model = SupervisedModel()
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weight_files_1[-1].as_posix()))
    model.to(device)
 
   
    test_labels = np.zeros(shape=(0,), dtype=np.float32)
    test_predictions = np.zeros(shape=(0, 2), dtype=np.float32)
    for iteration, test_batch in enumerate(test_loader):
        data, labels, metadata = test_batch
        data, labels = data[:, 5, :], labels.squeeze().long()
        #print(data.shape)
        data= torch.unsqueeze(data, dim=1)
        #print(data.shape)
        data, labels = data.to(device), labels.to(device)
        #print(labels.shape)

        # forward pass
        with torch.no_grad():
        
           
            
            features= network(data)
            predicted = model(features)
            #print(predicted.shape)

        test_labels = np.concatenate(
            (test_labels, labels.cuda().numpy()), axis=0)
        test_predictions = np.concatenate(
            (test_predictions, predicted.cuda().numpy()), axis=0)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried to send all data and labels to device (which is cuda:0)   but apparently some remains in cpu. I am newbie in pytorch sorry if it is too obvious.

Comment: This question would benefit from a stacktree to track where the issue occurs exactly. I notice two things based on the code:  This line could cause an issue:   `predicted.cuda().numpy()` based on the fact that numpy normaly only accepts CPU tensors. Also when casting a list to CUDA sometimes you will have to cast every element out of the list to CUDA seperatly.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed predicted.cuda().numpy() too and will change it to predicted.cpu().numpy. However, error comes before that. As you can see data and labels are sent to cuda device but something seems hardcoded to cpu that I could not detect.Networks and models are also sent to device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that `model` variable is not being copied to `cuda` device near `train_step_1` function definition. I am not sure why is everything being redefined here exactly, but the following may solve the issue:

```
train_loader_1, validation_loader_1, test_loader = verbio_data_loaders(args)
model = SupervisedModel()
model.to(device) # send the model to device here

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.learning_rate, weight_decay=args.weight_decay, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08)
loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```